# Programmatic configuration of PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter position

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Looking at [the Spring documentation for pre-authentication scenarios](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/preauth.html#siteminder-example-configuration), there seems to be a specific position for implementations of [AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html) when using XML configuration, namely

```
<security:http>
<!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->
<security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="refToMyPreAuthFilter" />
</security:http>
```

How can I achieve the same effect using programmatic configuration? Presumably, a filter for processing pre-authentication should be invoked before the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/technical-overview.html#exceptiontranslationfilter)? However, using something like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
          .addFilterBefore(new MyPreAuthFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class) 
        // ... additional configuration omitted
    }
}
```

does seem to lead to the filter not being invoked at all? Using just

```
http.addFilter(new MyPreAuthFilter())
```

seems to work, but I'm not sure the filter gets added at the right position (given the fact that the XML sample configuration uses a specific position for this filter)?

Looking at [Filter Ordering in the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/security-filter-chain.html#filter-ordering), using

```
http.addFilterBefore(new MyPreAuthFilter(), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
```

seems to be a good place and it works in tests.

Can anyone confirm this is the correct position for such a filter (or, else, name the correct position)?

Answer (score 4):

After browsing around a bit more, I found the following answer, I hope it's useful for some people.

*TL;DR* Using just `http.addFilter(new MyPreAuthFilter)` is correct, as the right order for subclasses of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` is automatically established.

So, here's the full explanation: Looking at [addFilter()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/1182d35d3cd9fc32bd6eda5a4c578f6e25c0e314/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L1016) of [HttpSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html), we see that it does the following

```
public HttpSecurity addFilter(Filter filter) {
        Class<? extends Filter> filterClass = filter.getClass();
        if (!comparitor.isRegistered(filterClass)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(...); // Complain about missing order
        }
        this.filters.add(filter);
        return this;
    }
```

First, note the following two facts:

1. [`HttpSecurity::addFilterBefore`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/1182d35d3cd9fc32bd6eda5a4c578f6e25c0e314/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L1003) and [`HttpSecurity::addFilterAfter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/1182d35d3cd9fc32bd6eda5a4c578f6e25c0e314/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java#L991) actually do call `HttpSecurity::addFilter` after first registering the given filter class `comparitor`, for example

   ```
   public HttpSecurity addFilterAfter(Filter filter, 
           Class<? extends Filter> afterFilter) {
       comparitor.registerAfter(filter.getClass(), afterFilter);
       return addFilter(filter);
   }
   ```
2. [`FilterComparitor::isRegistered`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ae6af5d73ce77f93926379f96371e84b1e9401f1/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java#L130) not only checks for the given class, but also for superclasses.

Now, remember that `http.addFilter(new MyPreAuthFilter())` where (`class MyPreAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter { ... }`) worked without throwing an exception. This means, that `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` (or one of its superclasses) must be already registered in `comparitor`. And, indeed, looking at the [constructor of FilterComparator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ae6af5d73ce77f93926379f96371e84b1e9401f1/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/FilterComparator.java#L61) we see the following order being established:

```
...
final int STEP = 100;
...
int order = 100;
put(ChannelProcessingFilter.class, order);
order += STEP;
put(ConcurrentSessionFilter.class, order);
order += STEP;
... // more filters
put(X509AuthenticationFilter.class, order);
order += STEP;
put(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class, order);
order += STEP;
...
put(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class, order);
        order += STEP;
...
put(ExceptionTranslationFilter.class, order);
order += STEP;
put(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class, order);
...
```

Therefore, using `HttpSecurity::addFilter` for subclasses of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` is the right answer.

Comment: ...and yes, it could also be found out quite quickly by properly reading the API documentation http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter- ...